# Asp.Net Core on Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to launch a Docker component with a ASP.NET Core application.

I use the following repo for my test : https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples

I ran the following commande without any issue :

```
git clone https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples aspnet-Home
cd aspnet-Home/HelloWeb
cat Dockerfile

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "helloweb.dll"]

sudo docker build –t helloweb .
sudo docker run -d helloweb
```

The image is visible using the `sudo docker images`, but the container doesn't launch and is not visible with `sudo docker ps`:

[image]

And if I browse my website, obsviously I do not see data.
Is the repo not good for my test ? Is there any mistake I do on the docker container creation ?

Running the `-it` command give me the following output:
[image]

Comment: Try running it with `-it` flag instead of `-d`, that should attach you to the standard input/output and may give you a clue as to why the container isn't starting.

Comment: Sorry for stealth edit, you can't have `-d` and `-it` at the same time, just do `-it`.

Comment: I just tried with `-it` command. Could you please help me solving this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you highlighted is because `helloweb.dll` you set as the `ENTRYPOINT` doesn't exist. There could be two reasons for it

### 1 You didn't build the project yet

In this case you should run `dotnet restore` from the project home directory, then navigate to `HelloWeb` directory and run `dotnet publish`. When I run this command, I see the following:

```
publish: Published to /code/HelloWeb/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish  
Published 1/1 projects successfully
```

### 2 You built the project, but the `ENTRYPOINT` path is wrong

`COPY . .` directive will copy everything from the current directory into your `app` directory. That means `HelloWeb.dll` will actually be in `bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish/` (or `bin/Release/...` for release builds).

**Option 1: Modify your entrypoint with the full path**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish/HelloWeb.dll"]
```

Your application should happily start and serve requests.

**Option 2: Modify your `COPY` directive**

Once your project has been published, everything you'll need to run it will be in the `publish` directory. You could copy the contents of that into the `/app` directory and your entrypoint will be correct. That would look like this

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish/ .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWeb.dll"]
```

---

You will also probably want to add the [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/expose) directive to tell Docker that your container will be listening on port 80.

---

When that succeeds, you should see (if you run in interactive mode)

```
docker run -it helloweb   
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://+:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

---

You could also use the `microsoft/dotnet:latest` image instead. That image comes with the SDK installed and a very convenient `run` command. The Dockerfile would look like this

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet restore

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

and you should be able to modify your source and build and run your container.

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot the `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000` command, that's why i failed. I thought `EXPOSE 5000` would be enough

Comment: @XavierW. That bit is actually from a deleted answer on this question, glad you're up and running.